# Cypress: Find plain text element under a span with other html element

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, cypress

How can we find the text element in the html DOM below. I need to get the text "Hello World1", "Hello World2", "Hello World3". I tried getting all span element with "class1" and called text() method but it's not returning the Hello world text.

Edit: I need a solution to iterate through the Hello World texts and compare it against an another text passed to a function and find the containing span element and click on it.

```
<div>
  <span class="class1">
     <span class="class2">
       "Text1"
     </span>
     "Hello World 1"
  </span>
  <span class="class1">
     <span class="class2">
       "Text2"
     </span>
     "Hello World 2"
  </span>
  <span class="class1">
     <span class="class2">
       "Text3"
     </span>
     "Hello World 3"
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding your function will help out.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the text and add a visible assertion like this:

```js
cy.contains('Hello World 1').should('be.visible')
cy.contains('Hello World 2').should('be.visible')
cy.contains('Hello World 3').should('be.visible')
```